# How to use Array method foreach() or map() to print Sudoku board onto a console?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a print function using .foreach() for Sudoku.
input is e.g

```
    var Sudoku =[[0,0,0,2,6,0,7,0,1], [6,8,0,0,7,0,0,9,0],[1,9,0,0,0,4,5,0,0],[8,2,0,1,0,0,0,4,0],[0,0,4,6,0,2,9,0,0],[0,5,0,0,0,3,0,2,8],
[0,0,9,3,0,0,0,7,4],[0,4,0,0,5,0,0,3,6],[7,0,3,0,1,8,0,0,0]];
```

and the expected output should be

```
0 0 0 2 6 0 7 0 1
6 8 0 0 7 0 0 9 0
1 9 0 0 0 4 5 0 0
8 2 0 1 0 0 0 4 0
0 0 4 6 0 2 9 0 0
0 5 0 0 0 3 0 2 8
0 0 9 3 0 0 0 7 4
0 4 0 0 5 0 0 3 6
7 0 3 0 1 8 0 0 0
```

conventionally we use for loops, but how can we use foreach() or any other array methods to attain the same result?
I tried the following code

```
function print(array) {
 let count = 0
    array.forEach(nested => nested.forEach(Element => {
        let out = "";
        out += Element + " ";
        console.log(out);
    }));
}
```

but the output is showing each element one by one like e.g

```
1 
0 
0 
4 
8 
9 
0
```

so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate and spread the inner arrays.

```js
var sudoku = [[0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 7, 0, 1], [6, 8, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0], [1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0], [8, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 8], [0, 0, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4], [0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 6], [7, 0, 3, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0]];

sudoku.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `console.log` each row, using `toString` method (and replace commas with spaces):

```js
var Sudoku =[
   [0,0,0,2,6,0,7,0,1],
   [6,8,0,0,7,0,0,9,0],
   [1,9,0,0,0,4,5,0,0],
   [8,2,0,1,0,0,0,4,0],
   [0,0,4,6,0,2,9,0,0],
   [0,5,0,0,0,3,0,2,8],
   [0,0,9,3,0,0,0,7,4],
   [0,4,0,0,5,0,0,3,6],
   [7,0,3,0,1,8,0,0,0]
];

Sudoku.forEach(row => console.log(row.toString().replace(/,/g," ")))
```

Comment: Nina's solution using `console.log(...row)` is more elegant

Answer (score 1):

It depends how particular you are about how it looks. The shortest solution would be

```js
console.table(Sudoku);
```

but that gives you a table, with headings, so might not be perfect.

If you can use `reduce` then I suggest:

```js
sudokutxt = Sudoku.reduce((acc, arr) => {acc.push(arr.join(' ')); return acc;}, []).join('\n');
```

My `forEach` solution is:

```js
let sudokutxt = '';
Sudoku.forEach(arr => sudokutxt += arr.join(' ') + '\n')
```